# GNU make uses same source file for each object file when part of dependency list is removed

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have a somewhat complicated source directory, and have written a makefile to compile it:

```
├── include
│   ├── subinc
│   │   ├── test_y.h
│   │   └── test_z.h
│   ├── test_w.h
│   └── test_x.h
├── makefile
├── src
│   ├── test_w.cpp
│   └── test_x.cpp
├── src2
│   ├── test_y.cpp
│   └── test_z.cpp
└── test.cpp
```

The makefile as shown below is working. But, I'm a bit confused why. It doesn't seem to be using `$(DEPS)`, since it gives paths like `./include/./include/subinc/test_y.h` when I echo it in the rule. That's obvious because of the `patsubst` line, but changing that to `patsubst %,%,$(INCLUDES)` breaks it too... (maybe that's the root of the whole problem!)

But, something funky happens when I remove that constant from the dependency list of the rule `%.o`, so the rule is just `%.o: $(SOURCES)`. Upon running make, it uses the first item in `$(SOURCES)` as the target for every call to g++ creating object files:

```
$ make
g++ -c -o test.o test.cpp -I./include -I./include/subinc
g++ -c -o src/test_x.o test.cpp -I./include -I./include/subinc
g++ -c -o src/test_w.o test.cpp -I./include -I./include/subinc
g++ -c -o src2/test_z.o test.cpp -I./include -I./include/subinc
g++ -c -o src2/test_y.o test.cpp -I./include -I./include/subinc
```

I figured that makes sense, because `$<` is used.

**But why does this only print the first in the dependency list when I take the second constant (of header files -- some even with bad format) out of the list?**

My thought is that somehow `make` is intelligently matching the `.cpp` files in the list to the corresponding `.h` files in the list, and then removing them from the list each time it runs the rule....

Thanks

---

**Makefile (working version, maybe full of bad practices...)**

```
INCDIR=./include
SRCDIR=./src

CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-I$(INCDIR) -I$(INCDIR)/subinc

INCLUDES=$(shell find . -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp")
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(INCDIR)/%,$(INCLUDES))

EXE=testexe
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard **/*.cpp)
OBJ=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

####RULES
%.o: $(SOURCES) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS)
    rm $(OBJ)
```

---

**EDIT**

If you'd like an MCVE for this, each `test_*.h` defines an empty class like

```
class T*{
    T*();  //defined in test_*.cpp to print "T* created"
    ~T*(); //defined in test_*.cpp to print "T* destroyed"
};
```

And the main `test.cpp` file just creates a pointer to each of the classes, and then deletes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues here.  First:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard **/*.cpp)
```

GNU make uses simple globbing, which does not understand `**`.  This behaves the same as `*`.  Since you only have one level of subdirectory this works for you but if you add another (sub-subdirectory) level, this won't match it.

Second, this is wrong:

```
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(INCDIR)/%,$(INCLUDES))
```

As you point out this changes the dependency paths from the (correct) `./include/xy/z.h` to the (incorrect) `./include/./include/xy/z.h`.  I'm not sure why you're trying to change anything at all here: why not just use the `INCLUDES` variable content directly?  Using `$(patsubst %,%,$(INCLUDES))` is a no-op; it has no effect.

Third, you should be using simple expansion (`:=`) for these types of assignments, so that they are not rerun every time the variable is used.

Next, this is wrong:

```
%.o: $(SOURCES) $(DEPS)
        $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

This will expand to something like this after `SOURCES` are resolved:

```
%.o: test.cpp src/test_w.cpp src/test_x.cpp src2/test_y.cpp src2/test_z.cpp ./include/include/subinc/test_y.h $(DEPS)
        $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

What this means is that *every* object file depends on *all* source files (and all `$(DEPS)`).  So if any source or header file ever changes ALL the object files will be rebuilt.  Clearly that's not what you want.

Also, the reason it always compiles the same file is that the recipe uses `$<`, which represents the first prerequisite, and the first prerequisite here is `test.cpp`, so that's what's always compiled.

When you create a pattern rule, (at least) the first source file should (almost always) be a pattern as well, so that it changes along with the target to build each object file (in this case).

So, you want your pattern rule to look like this:

```
%.o: %.cpp $(INCLUDES)
        $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Of course this does mean that every object file depends on all header files, so if you change any header file all your object files are rebuilt.  Maybe that's OK; if not you'll need to do [something more advanced](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

Lastly, you asked why it your makefile seems to work properly if you create bogus paths in the `$(DEPS)` variable.  Here's why: because those paths don't exist, make decides that your pattern rule doesn't apply (since not all the prerequisites can be created) and so it *ignores your pattern rule completely*.

Once that happens, make's default pattern rule for how to build an object file takes over, and that default rule builds things for you properly.  However, you may notice that if you modify any of the header files, make won't rebuild your object files (because it doesn't know about that prerequisite relationship).